# AWS EC2 Writable folder by the web server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a folder that is `chmod 755`, but its still not writable by the web server. What user:group do I need to set to have it be writable by the web server on EC2 AWS. `ec2-user`? `www`? `apache`?

Linux/Apache

Comment: What webserver? Apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Create an EC2 Instance and Install a Web Server](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Tutorials.WebServerDB.CreateWebServer.html)

```
sudo chown -R root:www /var/www
```

Add the www group to your EC2 instance if it doesnt exist:

```
sudo groupadd www
```

Comment: getting `chown: invalid group: ‘root:www’`

Comment: ok needed to do `sudo groupadd www`, please add to your answer and I'll accept